# QTP Scripts to Worsoft processes using java

Tags: java, qtp

Hello guys just want to ask if its Feasible to Convert QTP scripts to Worksoft processes  using java. Given that I have only the QTP Action/Steps,QTP Objects and QTP Test results for reference. Please help on this. I've searched some keywords on the net but no results found. Thank you in advance.